# Catch error in promise from a service in an Angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, es6-promise

Hi everyone running into a problem with a post service I created in angular. Struggling to catch the error from my component when I call the service. I was able to catch the error from the service but I need to do this from my component to properly handle the error. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**Service**

```
sendData(obj) {
 let promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
   this.http.post(this.URL, obj, this.httpOptions)
     .toPromise()
     .then(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
        resolve(res);
      }
     )
     //.catch((err) => { 
     //  console.log(err);
     //  throw err;
     //});
   });
  return promise;
}
```

**Component**

```
this._myservice.sendData(this.myobj)
  .then(function (res) {
    console.log('data sent');
  })
  .catch(error => {
      console.warn('from component:', error);
      // this console warn never gets logged out
  });
```

Do I need to update something in my service to allow me to catch the error from the component?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're creating your own `Promise` here, but you never call `reject` if the `Promise` you're *wrapping* *rejects* (throws an error). This is known as the [the `new Promise` antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). In your case, you can simply remove this wrapper and replace the call to `resolve` with a `return` in order to achieve what you need, like so:

```
sendData(obj) {
    return this.http.post(this.URL, obj, this.httpOptions)
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            return res;
        });
}
```

In order to provide more context, you could *fix* your original problem by calling `reject`. This would look like this:

```
// DONT'T DO THIS
sendData(obj) {
   let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       this.http.post(this.URL, obj, this.httpOptions)
           .toPromise()
           .then(res => {
               console.log(res);
               resolve(res);
            })
            .catch((err) => { 
                console.log(err);
                reject(err); // Here.
            });
        });
    return promise;
}
```

But, as I said above, this is overcomplicated and unnecessary. I hope that it demonstrates how the `Promise` your component has access to could never see errors that occurred in the HTTP call.